# what should i do for undefined reference to `WinMain@16' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c

I am new to C language. I'm currently trying to create an algorithm to make a rank of scores, following a textbook. This is a code shown in the textbook.

```
struct data{
   int rank;
   int score;
};

void rank1 (struct data *x, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    
    for ( i = 0 ; i < n; i++ ) 
        x [i]. rank = 1;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    if(x [i].score < x [j].score)
    x [i].rank++;

}
```

Then I got an error saying below.

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\soohk\OneDrive\desktop\programming\edition 1\" && gcc tempCodeRunnerFile.c -o tempCodeRunnerFile && "c:\Users\soohk\OneDrive\desktop\programming\edition 1\"tempCodeRunnerFile
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xc0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What can I do for this situation?

Comment: You're missing the main function. The program can't run without it.

Comment: Or even `WinMain` since it isn't proper C.

Comment: @anastaciu  Thank you for answering. How and where should I add these things?

Comment: This is fairly basic C stuff. Your textbook should guide you. If you [edit] your question, please provide a [example].